# Does "I had the same issue" count as "fluff"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've just encountered [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17804963)… I'm having trouble deciding whether "I had the same issue" should be OK to remove as fluff.

I've mostly dealt with fluff like this:

- thanks in advance
- hope it helps
- help is much appreciated

In other words, the "Stack Overflow Hates Manners" stuff. So this sort of thing is a bit out of my area of expertise.

Ignoring the other problems with this edit, was "I had the same issue" OK to remove?

Comment: It is not fluff.  Acknowledging that you got a repro for the OP's problem is useful info and gives credit to the proposed solution.  The edit was properly rejected.

Comment: Not fluff for me too. It tells you the motivation and source of their answer... was it from a helpful user just swinging by, or was it from a helpful user that _actually experienced_ the same problem - fought through hours of voodoo magic code - battled demons in the hidden dark corners of codebase! Really helpful in some cases to see how someone else who had the same thing resolved their problem.

Comment: I think it is fluff, since "had the same issue" can by inferred from the remainder of the answer. However, I don't know if that alone is enough of a reason to edit an answer.

Comment: Yes, it's fluff. It doesn't provide any useful information; you don't need to know whether an answerer has personally had the issue before, you just need to know how to solve the problem. It's certainly not important enough information to include in a sentence of its own.

Comment: In an ideal world, SO questions would *always* provide a decent way for an answerer to get a repro.  I wish.  In practice that however happens rarely.  I always, always note whether an answer is based on a repro and a solution that solved the mishap or is an educated guess based on the provided info.  Unfortunately the post being discussed stinks pretty heavily so it is easy to get biased towards fluff.

Comment: Note that, in the mean time, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47056326) that edit was suggested to has been deleted by its author after receiving [two "Recommend Deletion" reviews in the LQP queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17805195). Based on the comments they left, the reviewers seem to have thought it was either "commentary on another post" or an "I’m having this problem, too" post.

Comment: Definitely not fluff. There's a difference between a "I've had this problem before and this is how I solved it" kind of answer and a "you should try this and see if it helps" kind of answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Definitely not enough for an edit - something glossed over is that the "for me" you're referring to was added during the edit.  It just rephrased the answer without actually removing anything, whether or not it was fluff.

Comment: @AlexK I'm of the opinion probing questions like that are a better fit for comments, but I don't disagree they outnumber tested answers. I would go further and say "This tested, verified answer solves your problem as asked" is different from "I solved a similar problem by..." which makes stating that even more valuable.

Comment: IMO the editor in question actually made the grammar in the post slightly worse, from "Had the same issue, actually just restored all NuGet packages from Console and that did the trick." to "Restored all NuGet packages from [the] Console [,] that did the trick for me.". My guess is, the editors were using the "actively harm" parts of the message. That canned reject message is rather vague, we're kind of left to guess whether they meant "too minor", "does absolutely nothing", or "harms the post".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The question is really, does the "Had the same issue" text add more information to the answer?

In a simple question with an easily reproducible problem you could safely assume it was a given that the person answering had solved the same issue.

However with more complicated cases involving archaic languages or specialised software I'd say that adding "Had the same issue" explains that you're not just making a guess as some answers might be, but instead have reproduced it and found a solution.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548780/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-netframework-version-v4-6-2-were-not-f/47056326#47056326) you're talking about falls I'd say into the second category, where answers could have easily been educated guesses about the .Net framework system, rather than direct replications of the issue, so I'd have believed the "fluff" did add information to the answer.

In a perfect world however, we'd have less pot-shot answers so wouldn't need the clarification between guesses and solutions, but that's down more to the question being asked.

Comment: So we've got a party saying no, a party saying yes, and a party saying it depends on the question? Nice.

Comment: Do we tolerate answers that are just guesses and have not actually been tried? I thought if someone just guessed, the answer should be downvoted into oblivion. I would never dream about posting an answer unless I have actually verified that it *answers* the question.

Comment: Totally should be the case @Polygnome, but in cases where they can't produce a MCVE people might start making guesses based off accumulated knowledge, that then helps the user.

Comment: @Polygnome I think less than 1% of the answers I give are actually coded and tried.  I have better things to do than write and test code for every answer I give-  my productivity here would drop by 98%.  The vast majority of questions don't need verifying to correctly answer.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with adding text like that in an answer is that it makes your answer look like a "mee toooo" statement rather than a solution. People may misunderstand and flag as "not an answer", and may downvote.  Better to leave off language like that than tempt confusion.

Comment: That would be "I *have* the same problem", not "I *had* the same problem".

Comment: @StephenLeppik - Even so, we frequently see people mistakenly flagging and voting to delete answers that start with "I had the same problem". Not everyone actually reads the whole answer before voting / flagging, unfortunately.

Comment: @BradLarson then that's a problem with flaggers and reviewers.

Comment: @StephenLeppik That's the problem with *humanity*.  Until you can separate the humanity from SO, better to err on the side of clarity.

Comment: Agreed. I came across a handful of these in the LQP queue last week. They had all been flagged (IMO) because they looked at first glance like a "Me Too". In all cases I edited to clarify that it was actually an answer.

Comment: @Stephen Leppik: No one is implying otherwise. How would you propose to solve that kind of problem, though?

Comment: "I *solved* that problem ..." might be more clear. it communicates the same context (that you had the same problem) but also makes it clear that the answer is not an "me too" answer, but a *solution*.

Comment: You can fix this by offering the solution *first* and then adding a line "I had the same issue and this fixed it for me", which IMHO also makes for a better answer since it offers the solution *first* without introduction.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that is noise/fluff.

It is enough to know what can be done. One can leave the "did the trick for me" part, because that is the reference. It is not a very good reference, it would be better if the answerer could point at an authorative resource like MSDN. But since the answerer doesn't have that, it is good to let future readers know that the source of the answer is personal experience.

There is one other issue with that particular edit, it introduces a grammatical error.

Comment: It seems someone disagrees. I guess I'll wait a little before making a decision.

Comment: I've seen the comment by Hans Passant. I for one feel "I had the same issue" is the fluff part, but I do advise to leave an indication that personal experience is the source of the information.

Comment: agreed; it is not the fact that you reproduced it that is interesting - the steps you took to reproduce it are. They may even vary from the steps to reproduce that the OP has which could be an indication that the answer is actually not going to be correct. I compare it to someone claiming that they profiled a performance problem correctly; *I don't believe you stranger, provide details*.